# How do I send email from AppController in CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to send an email from `AppController` in my CakePHP 2.0 app.  It works fine if I send it from the `PagesController`, but I need to be able to send from `AppController` as well.

I have:

```
function sendSystemEmail($to = EMAIL_CONTACT, $from = EMAIL_FROM, $subject = null, $body = null, $view = null, $vars = null) {
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->viewVars(array(
            'body' => $body,
            'vars' => $vars
    ));
    $email->template($view)
            ->emailFormat('html')
            ->from($from)
            ->to($to)
            ->subject($subject)
            ->send();
    return;
}
```

When I use this, I don't get any errors, but the email doesn't arrive.  I can't see that there's any different between this and the code I have in `PagesController`, so I'm assuming that there's something that `AppController` doesn't have access to maybe?  I can't figure out what though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharon, you're not putting the configuration method.. this parameter can put in the constructor of classEmail too, this way..

```
$email = new CakeEmail('pop3'); //can be smtp or the protocole you are using..
```

or

```
$email->config('pop3')
```

and you need to define the connection here..
**./app/Config/email.php**

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $pop3 = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
```